# Permissions errors when connecting from Windows7 to a SAMBA server

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, samba

I've got a Win7 system that connects to my Ubuntu server, where I keep my music and other media. I can access my media files from the Win7 machine, but I often get permissions errors, for example when trying to update tags on tracks.

On the Linux machine, I have a group "group1", which contains the user "bob". "bob" is also my login account for that Linux machine. I have a mapped network drive in Win7, which also uses the "bob" username to login.

My samba config has

```
security = user
guest account = nobody

[share]
   comment = File Server Share
   path = /media/md0
   browsable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0775
```

Given this setup, I'd expect applications on my Win7 machine to be able to update MP3 files on the Linux machine that belong to "group1", but instead I get permission errors. I'm wondering if Windows does something funny with the login credentials it presents to Linux, or perhaps there's something wrong in my samba config?

I can't understand why I can edit files in Linux as user "bob", but I can't edit the files from Win7 when accessing with the same username and credentials. Any suggestions for things to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was down to Linux file permissions. The files had been created with the Samba "create mask" of 775, but were also being restricted to 722 by the bittorrent app I was using.

Fixing up the transmission-daemon config to remove the umask so that they were created 775 (as intended) has resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remember within linux/samba you have Linux username/passwords and Samba username/passwords. These 2 are not mutually exclusive. Doublecheck they are both set to the same thing with the same permissions.

Comment: Please see my edit including the samba config; as I understand it the "security = user" directive should map samba users to linux users. Thanks.

Comment: I've not used that config myself so can't comment further. Have you tried what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: If they were different then I don't think I'd be able to access the files in the first place. I'm fairly sure this is actually down to the permissions on the files themselves, I'll play with that a bit more and post an update. Ta.

Comment: The Samba username/password can be totally different to the Linux password without affecting the Samba permissions (Samba keeps its own Password & Permissions databases)